# catch FileNotFoundException Java

Tags: java, swing

I have this code, what it basically does is, it gets the string typed in a JTextPanel then assigns it to "conec". Then it creates a graph with the lines of that file.

The `FileManagement.load_file(conec)` method looks for the file with that name in the project folder and proceeds to run the code. Thing is, when I type the wrong name of file, I'm getting the FileNotFoundException, and I want it to say the "Invalid file", message but it's just not working it just keeps running the program.

This is what I have tried so far but not working, it gives the error and keeps running.

```
try {
    String conec = archivo.getText();
    Grafo g = FileManagement.load_file(conec);
    cl = g.getClientes();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid File.");
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "File loaded correctly.");
```

}

Comment: In the case of a FileNotFoundException, you're putting up two MessageDialogs, one saying Invalid File, and the other File loaded correctly.

Comment: What NomadMaker said. I suppose you should do something like "return;" to return or "throw e;" to rethrow the exception in the catch block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After executing a `catch` block, the control automatically moves to statements following all the `catch` and `finally` blocks belonging to the `try` keyword.

### What you can do (*Any one of these*):

1. ```
    java 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid File.");
    e.printStackTrace();
   ```
2. ```
    java 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid File.");
    System.exit(-1);
   ```
3. ```
    java 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid File.");
    return;
   ```
4. ```
    java 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid File.");
    throw new Exception(e);
   ```
5. ```
    java 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    throw new Exception(e, "Invalid File.");
   ```

Comment: When i try any of these, im getting this error msg: "exception filenotfoundexception is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement" any idea?

Comment: These are meant to replace the `catch()` in the snippet you have shown. The rest of the code will remain same. Futhermore, you can place only one of these in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The 5 options of the other answer all work just fine, but there's an even more simple solution here in my opinion.
As a commenter pointed out, the message dialog that's supposed to open in the "correct" case will always open no matter if an Exception is thrown or not. I'm guessing you tried to simulate an `else` statement without actually writing the `else` which is possible:

```java
if(somethingIsTrue)
{
    doSomething();
}
doSomethingElse();
```

In this example, the method call to `doSomethingElse()` is an `else` statement despite never actually coding `else`. This behaviour is not replicated by a try/catch block. (If you never made this assumption and I'm just pulling stuff out of my ass ignore this part up to now),

I think the simplest fix, considering that the "correct" message should pop up when the `try` block executes succesfully, would be to simply add it to the `try` block:

```java
try 
{
    String conec = archivo.getText();
    Grafo g = FileManagement.load_file(conec);
    cl = g.getClientes();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "File loaded correctly.");
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid File.");
}
```